# How can i create this type of tab view in React native app?

Tags: react-native

How can I create a tab view like the one below using React Native?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Use any of the tab view library available. like **[this](https://github.com/happypancake/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)**.
- Then render your tab header view with custom background (You can take image background). **[This](https://github.com/happypancake/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)** library has function `renderTabBar`.
- Benifit of using libraries is that you will get good animations when scrolling.